# Visual Studio Python PIP Times out looking for urllib2

Tags: python, visual-studio

I am new to python on Visual Studio.

-----Here is my code-------------------------------

import urllib2

---

I need urllib2, but when I use PIP to get it, PIP times out.

What do I do? Do I setup a proxy? or can I manually import it somehow??

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`urllib2`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) is only available in Python 2, and is included as part of the standard library, which is why `pip` can't find it. For Python 3, you can use the various components of [`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html), or for a much easier time of it, use the excellent [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org) module, which *is* available via `pip`.